# Gnome 42: Go to next active static workspace keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have 8 static workspaces and depending on the application type (e.g. browser, media, email etc), I distribute my windows between them. Sometimes I will have windows in workspace 1 (browser) and workspace 3 (system settings), but none on workspace 2 (code).

In this case, I would like to be able to switch from workspace 1 -> workspace 3 without passing by workspace 2. This would be especially useful for workspaces that are far apart.

Is there some keyboard shortcut or a way to create such a shortcut that allows me to go to the next or previous active workspaces?

Edit:

To clarify, if I am in the `Code` workspace, is there a shortcut to switch to the next active workspace, which in this case is `Media`. The reason for why would be useful is that I do not have to look up to check which workspace is active or hopefully not have to stretch my hands to press Super+8.

[image: workspace indicator]

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 with GNOME 42.2 there is an app for just that purpose.

Go to `Extension Manager` and install `Simple indication of workspaces`.

This will place an indicator in the top left of the system tray (before Activities) from which you can select the workspace you wish to go to directly.

[image]

If not already installed, you can install `Gnome Extension Manager by following the  [instructions here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/manage-gnome-extensions-ubuntu-2204/)

I've tested this app and found it to work very well. After the screen has gone blank, if you have `Screen Blank` set in `Power` options, on being restored, only the workspaces with an activity will be presented in the panel.

If that doesn't work for you. clicking on the 9 dot icon at the bottom of the dock will show the workspaces from which you can select the one you want to select.